# How can I understand this 2 pieces of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
 
  function sortPeople() {
    const sortedPeople = [...peopleList];
    let sortCount = counter;
    if (sortCount === 2) {
      sortCount = 1;
      setCounter(1);
    } else {
      sortCount += 1;
      setCounter(sortCount);
    }
    if (sortCount < 3) {
      sortedPeople.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (sortCount === 1) {
          return x.eaten === y.eaten
            ? 0
            : x.eaten === "No"
            ? -1
            : 1;
        } else if (sortCount === 2) {
          return x.eaten === y.eaten
            ? 0
            : x.eaten === "No"
            ? 1
            : -1;
        }
      });

      setPeopleList(sortedPeople);
    }
  }
```

```
  const [counterCount, setCounterCount] = useState(0);
  function sortCountPeople() {
    const sortedCountPeople = [...customerList];
    let sortCountVisit = counterCount;
    if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
      sortCountVisit = 1;
      setCounterCount(1);
    } else {
      sortCountVisit += 1;
      setCounterCount(sortCountVisit);
    }

    sortedCountPeople.sort(function (x, y) {
      if (sortCountVisit === 1) {
        return x.number - y.number;
      } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
        return y.number - x.number;
      }
    });
    setPeopleList(sortedCountPeople);
  }
```

I have trouble understanding : the sort logic from the if sort count is < 3, then theres like ? : 0 -1 1 and also for sorting count theres like y-x and x-y so can someone explain this code to mean that would be great thank you in advance very much
!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description

Comment: @DrewReese kindly do elaborate.

Comment: @DrewReese from if sortcount<3 part all the way

Comment: Has my answer sufficiently addressed your questions, or is something still unclear?

Comment: @DrewReese still unclear

Comment: What precisely is still unclear? Is there a specific piece? Are the nested ternaries tripping you up?

Comment: @DrewReese do not understand the question marks and syntaxes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233593/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-fyceheist).

Answer (score 2):

## Snippet 1

> ```
> if (sortCount < 3) {
>   sortedPeople.sort(function (x, y) {
>     if (sortCount === 1) {
>       return x.eaten === y.eaten
>         ? 0
>         : x.eaten === "No"
>         ? -1
>         : 1;
>     } else if (sortCount === 2) {
>       return x.eaten === y.eaten
>         ? 0
>         : x.eaten === "No"
>         ? 1
>         : -1;
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```

If `sortCount` is 0(*?*), 1, or 2 (*i.e. less than 3*) then the `sortedPeople` array will be sorted.

Using a compare function:

> ```
> function compare(a, b) {
>   if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
>     return -1;
>   }
>   if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
>     return 1;
>   }
>   // a must be equal to b
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

In other words, if `-1` is returned then `a` comes *before* `b` and should move forward in the array, if `1` is returned then `a` comes *after* `b` and should move back in the array, and if `0` is returned `a` and `b` are considered "equal" and `a` stays where it's at.

In your callback if `x.eaten` is equal to `y.eaten` then `0` is returned and `x` doesn't move. If `sortCount` equals 1 and `x` isn't eaten yet then `-1` is returned and `x` moves back in the array, otherwise it moves forward. If `sortCount` equals `2` then this is reversed, if `x` isn't eaten yet then `1` is returned and it moves forward, otherwise it moves back.

### Update

Since there seems to be confusion over the ternary syntax I'll rewrite it using if-else statements.

```
function (x, y) {
  if (sortCount === 1) {
    if (x.eaten === y.eaten) {
      return 0;
    } else if (x.eaten === "No") {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  } else if (sortCount === 2) {
    if (x.eaten === y.eaten) {
      return 0;
    } else if (x.eaten === "No") {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

## Snippet 2

> ```
> sortedCountPeople.sort(function (x, y) {
>   if (sortCountVisit === 1) {
>     return x.number - y.number;
>   } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
>     return y.number - x.number;
>   }
> });
> ```

When comparing numbers the compare function can be much simpler:

> ```
> function compareNumbers(a, b) {
>   return a - b;
> }
> ```

If the result is negative, or less than zero, then `a` comes *before* `b` and should move forward in the array, if the result is positive, or greater than zero, then `a` comes *after* `b` and should move back in the array, and if the result is `0` they were equal and `a` stays where it's at.

In the callback if `sortCountVisit` equals 1 then the result will move `x` forward if it is less than `y` and back if it is greater than `y`. If `sortCountVisit` equals 2 then this is reversed, `x` moves back if less than `y` and forward if greater than `y`.